# grandtotal and runningtotal for multiple pages in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, cumulative-sum

I have a gridview with total at the footer. My paging allows only 25 records for each page. So when there are multiple pages there should be running total and the grand total. Could me anyone help me with the code. below are the code for the total for a column.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" ShowFooter="True" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="30px"                                                                                                          HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Wrap="True">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblcriteria" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CRITERIA_N") %>' />
</ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Period" SortExpression="PERIOD_N" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
 HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Wrap="True">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblPERIOD_N" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PERIOD_N") %>' /></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Receipts" SortExpression="CHECK_AMT_A_USD" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" HeaderStyle-Width="70px">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblReceipt" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CHECK_AMT_A_USD") %>' /></ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lbltotReceipt" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblgrangtot" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</column>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridView grid = sender as GridView;
    DataRowView tableData = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
    DataTable dt = Session["List"] as DataTable;       

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        totreceipt = 0; 
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label lblReceipt = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblReceipt");
        totreceipt += Convert.ToDecimal(tableData["CHECK_AMT_A_USD"]);
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {

        Label lbltotReceipt = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbltotReceipt");
        lbltotReceipt.Text = string.Format("{0:N2}", totreceipt);
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Total:";
    }

}
```

I couldn't go through the sample ones. Those are pretty confusing. So Kindly help with the coding.

UPDATE:

Here is my SP..

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[SP_AVG_DAYS]      

@Cont_C char(1),      
@Month_dd varchar(10),        
@MonYr_S VARCHAR(12),        
@2_Div_Code VARCHAR(2)       

As                  

DECLARE @SelectText varChar(2000)                         
DECLARE @Table varchar(30)      

IF @2_Div_Code <> ''    
BEGIN    
 IF @MonYr_S='Div_Reg'    
 BEGIN    
  SET @Table='VW_BPDP_DIV_REG'    
 END    
 IF @MonYr_S='Div_Area'    
 BEGIN     
  SET @Table='VW_BPDP_DIV_AREA'    
 END    
 IF @MonYr_S='Div_Loc'    
 BEGIN     
  SET @Table='VW_BPDP_DIV_LOC'    
 END 
 END


SET @SelectText='SELECT CRITERIA_N,HEADER_N,PERIOD_N,CHECK_RECEIPT, BP_DAYS 
FROM ' + @Table + '       
WHERE  CONT_C = ''' + @Cont_C + ''' AND DIV_C = ''' + @2_Div_Code + ''' '     

EXECUTE(@SelectText)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the running total is ok from your code..
the grand total you can compute it by saving the running total from each page into viewState or Session.
Or do you want to show the grand total for all entries from the beginning?

I assume you do not need the GrandTotal for all tables, so I would suggest to have another varchar variable : @SelectCriteria which you set in the places you would like to have a grand total

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[SP_AVG_DAYS]   
@Cont_C char(1),      
@Month_dd varchar(10),        
@MonYr_S VARCHAR(12),        
@2_Div_Code VARCHAR(2),        
@2_Reg_Code VARCHAR(3),        
@2_Area_Code VARCHAR(3),        
@2_CR_Code VARCHAR(3)       

As                  

DECLARE @SelectText varChar(2000)                         
DECLARE @SelectCriteria varChar(100)    
DECLARE @Table varchar(30)      

IF @2_Div_Code <> ''    
BEGIN    
IF @MonYr_S='Div_Reg'    
 BEGIN    
   SET @SelectCriteria =', Sum(_columnWithValues) as GrandTotal'
   SET @Table='IA_VPAYMENTS_BPDP_DIV_REG'    
 END    
IF @MonYr_S='Div_Area'    
  BEGIN     
SET @Table='IA_VPAYMENTS_BPDP_DIV_AREA'    

END    
 IF @MonYr_S='Div_Loc'    
 BEGIN     
  SET @Table='IA_VPAYMENTS_BPDP_DIV_LOC'    
 END 
 END


SET @SelectText='SELECT CRITERIA_N,HEADER_N,PERIOD_N,CHECK_RECEIPT, BP_DAYS' + @SelectCriteria + ' FROM ' + @Table + 'WHERE  CONT_C = ''' + @Cont_C + ''' AND DIV_C = ''' + @2_Div_Code + ''' '     
EXECUTE(@SelectText)
```

Comment: A very simple possibility is to return the grand total in the stored procedure you are using (just add a sum at the end of the select), but if you have no possibility of doing so, create a function for the label by addind Text='<%# Calculate() %>' and then in the c# code behind you can request from the objectdatasource the full table and sum the correct values. foreach (DataRowView item in objDataSource.Select()){ //sum values}

Comment: Can u just help me with the sample code to add the total in the stored procedure.. ill try that first..

Comment: Generally you should have something like Select val1, val2, val3, Sum(val3) as GrandTotal From table

Comment: Sorry about the edit.. I dnt realize that it was your answer, instead i thought i posted the SP wrong..

Comment: the SP executed successfully but when i execute the store procedure im getting an error

Comment: what is the error? did u try it on sql server to check that it works and then in the project?

Comment: u were right.. I got the output.. it was a careless mistake from my side.. Thanks.